# Is there a modern ram drive hardware (pcie memory drive)?

Tags: ssd, ramdisk

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYbCYgYZVT8) and got inspired that this kind of hardware could be used as a LVM cache for m.2 pcie SSD. I believe that this would greatly improved performance even if it's size would be pretty small compared to SSD's size. For today's standards it would need to be pciexpress 3.0 or 4.0 x16 (that would be great amount of bandwidth and much smaller latency compared to SSDs).

Thanks.

Comment: Myself suggest using a NVMe SSD instead that device, because its latency is lower as that shown in the Video and is more reliable as that device

Comment: Or if NVMe is too slow for you then look at Intel's Optane memory.

Comment: nvme is afaik faster as optain specially in write Performance

Comment: Broadcom do ICs for hardware-RAID. See https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-on-chip to find manufactors of controller-boards.

Answer (score 4):

Last hardware board for consumers I found was [Gigabyte GC-RAMDISK i-RAM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EPM9NC) circa 2006. These fell out of favor as they require battery backup like array cache modules, and as non-volatile solid state got faster.

Yes, [reading a MB](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html) from DRAM is about 4 microseconds, faster than 62 us or so from SSD. For in the best case a 15x speed up, are you willing to bet the integrity of your data on the battery backup of your RAM disk?

Actually, it won't be that good, because [kernels are not usually optimized for latency that low](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc19-lee-gyusun.pdf).

Consider the alternative of having lots of DRAM for volatile memory like usual. The OS can use it for caching. You still could have a LVM cache disk, but maybe just a high endurance, low latency NVMe to eat the writes.

Comment: Ya as annoying an a conclusion as this is (esp if we have any significant amount of older generation RAM sitting around as paperweights), it just seems like provisioning your machine to have more system memory is just the way to go. Now if only AMD will hurry up and allow us to build Threadripper Pro rigs.